# Identifying occluded texture patches from a large dataset

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, classification

My hypothetical task at hand is to be able to from a single from above picture of a geometrically undistorted beverage can, give its classification (e.g. brand & name of beverage). No segmentation is needed. The input to the classification function is just a view, ONE view, of the can from any of its sides. The dataset should be large, around 2000 different kinds of beverages. The cans all have the same size. For training, each can is rotated a few hundred times to include almost any angle.

Any ideas what would be the best way to approach this? To me it seems like a texture recognition problem, where the shape of the object itself is irrelevant. Classification should also be fast, so template matching is ruled out. If someone can just point out the right direction for me it would be a huge step forwards. No ideas I come up with seems really fitting for the task. Local features (SIFT/SURF) etc? Too general. A brand can have the same logo on different beverages they produce. Neural nets? The can can look very different on different sides, which will mess up the training if they all map to the same label. Bag of words? HOGs/colour histograms etc for training an SVM? Something completely different that I don't know that I don't know about perhaps?

Comment: Somehow related to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832257/sift-is-not-finding-any-features-in-reference-image-in-opencv

Answer (score 0):

One good approach would be model the shape of the can, so you can map the texture and the labels in the can to a planar rectangle. From this you could do template matching using low resolution versions or gaussian pyramidal based template matching to make a fast match.

Second option would be to extract SIFT or SURF keypoints of this 'planarized' image and try to find corresponding points in the training set. Although same logos or texts might appear on several different cans, you can use the locations of the keypoints to differentiate between the cans.